# sqllite database field how to store array list

Tags: android

```
CREATE TABLE 
hindibible(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
            Book INTEGER ,
            Chapter INTEGER ,
            Version INTEGER ,
            TB TEXT ,
            NKJ TEXT );
```

I'm creating sqlite table and also insert all values . in the above sqlite table how to  NKJ field data to store arraylist.

Comment: I guess you should normalize your database and make one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I use these methods.  There are a few important things to note:

1. sqlite tables are particular - make sure the data you're inserting fits the columns of the table you're sending it to.
2. insertArrayList iterates through each row, but does not commit the transaction until it's all done. This is for performance.
3. rowValues converts the row data into a string with comma separators, which is what sql uses
4. rowValues also replaces single-quotes with two single-quotes, which sqlite uses as an escape character. You may have to use others depending on what you expect the contents of your data to be

The code:

```
private String rowValues(ArrayList<String> rowdata) {
    StringBuilder valString = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";
    valString.append("(");
    for (String cell : rowdata) {
        valString.append(separator + "'" + cell.replace("'", "''") + "'");
        separator = ",";
    }
    valString.append(")");
    return valString.toString();
}

public void insertArrayList(SQLiteDatabase db, String Table, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tabledata) {
    Cursor cols = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table + " limit 0",null);
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        db.execSQL("delete from " + Table);
        int Xtra = cols.getColumnCount() - tabledata.get(0).size();
        for (ArrayList<String> item : tabledata) {
            for (int a=0;a<Xtra;a++) {item.add("");}
            db.execSQL("insert into " + Table + " values " + rowValues(item) + ";");
            //Log.i("insertArrayList","insert into " + Table + " values " + rowValues(item) + ";");
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DBWrapper", "insertArrayList error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```